# Add silence at the end of a .wav file created from a .mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wav

I want to generate .wav files from .mp4 ones using ffmpeg. In this command I want to include an option so that all the wav files have the same duration (add some seconds of silence at the end of each generated file).

I saw [here](https://superuser.com/questions/579008/add-1-second-of-silence-to-audio-through-ffmpeg) that you can add some options but they don't seem to work in my case.

This is what I have so far :

```
command = "ffmpeg -i " + mp4_file_path + " -filter_complex [1:a][0:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 -ab 160k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -vn " + wav_file_path

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: I edited the code. The error I get is Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [1:a][0:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1.

Comment: You're attempting to use the concat filter with two inputs, but you only have one input. You need another input such as a filter that generates silence. See "Using the concat filter" section in the link you provided. However, an easier method is to use the apad filter as shown in the same link. You'll need a "git nightly" build of ffmpeg though because it's a new feature. See [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds. I don't know your OS so I can't give you more detailed suggestions regarding downloading it.